# Spectre V1 PoC Code

Tags: spectre, poc

I try to understand the Spectre PoC by Erik August (https://gist.github.com/ErikAugust/724d4a969fb2c6ae1bbd7b2a9e3d4bb6).
In line 76 it says

```
x = ((j % 6) - 1) & ~0xFFFF;
```

So I know `&` is a bitwise AND and `~` returns a bitwise complement. If `j%6` is `0` I get why `x=FFF.FF0000`.
But I wonder why `x=0` in the other cases. Why isn't it e.g. `0xFFFF0001`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

~0xFFFF gives you 0xFFFF_0000

The result of ((j % 6) - 1) could be -1 (0xFFFF_FFFF)
or 0-4

For 0 to 4, if you AND it with 0xFFFF_0000, that will be 0.

example:

```
0xFFFF_0000
0x0000_0001 
----AND----
0x0000_0000
```